# how to capture handwritten amount from a check in c# using any third party libraries/softwares

Tags: c#

I have to capture the handwritten amount from a Check(US) in c#. Which software should I use?
I have tried A2iA software but this does not resolve my problem.

If any one worked with any other software or libraries which can capture amount from check, please let me know.

Comment: you could look for a c# wrapper for openCV

Comment: @mgttlinger What do u mean by c# wrapper for openCV. will u please provide me some more information or links on it.

Comment: openCV is typically programmed in Python, C++ or another script language I dont remember at the moment. There are however wrappers for Java, C# and many other programming languages like [EMGUCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). As far as I know for recognising handwritten characters the way to go is to program a neural network and train it to recognise the characters. [Paper on that here](http://cs.earlham.edu/~twright09/paper.pdf)

Comment: Look up OCR, which stands for Optical Character Recognition. There are proprietary closed-source products out there, which are typically expensive and don't work. [Pegasus/Accusoft](http://www.accusoft.com/forms.htm) at least worked, some of the time, but I felt pretty dubious about trusting it to read anything important. I haven't seen anything that claimed to be able to read cursive handwriting. Open source code is usually better, so I would give openCV a shot first.